# dpdk Rx TCP checksum failed

Tags: dpdk

I am using the checksum offloads feature in DPDK and it did not working under virtual macine.
virtual port only support TCP checksum and do not support IP checksum.

so I config rxmode.offload txmode.offloads as below:

```c
rxmode.offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM 
txmode.offloads = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM
... ...
rte_eth_dev_configure()
```

For TX, I set the following parameters, it works good.

```c
mbuf->l2_len = sizeof(*ethhdr)
mbuf->l3_len = ip header len
mbuf-ol_flags = RTE_MBUF_F_TX_IPV4 | RTE_MBUF_F_TX_TCP_CKSUM
```

For RX, It will execute the following code:

```
 In drivers/net/virtio/virtio_rxtx.c  virtio_rx_offload function :
 929     if (hdr->flags & VIRTIO_NET_HDR_F_NEEDS_CSUM) {
 930         hdrlen = hdr_lens.l2_len + hdr_lens.l3_len + hdr_lens.l4_len;
 931         if (hdr->csum_start <= hdrlen && l4_supported) {
 932             m->ol_flags |= RTE_MBUF_F_RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE;
 933         } else {
                ...  ...
 952         }
 953     } else if (hdr->flags & VIRTIO_NET_HDR_F_DATA_VALID && l4_supported) {
 954         m->ol_flags |= RTE_MBUF_F_RX_L4_CKSUM_GOOD;
 955     }
```

hdr->flags & VIRTIO_NET_HDR_F_NEEDS_CSUM is true(line 929)

hdrlen = 54

hdr->csum_start = 34

so m->ol_flags = RTE_MBUF_F_RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE(line 932)

This cause rx checksum failed.

I think the code should enter line 953 not line 929, but I don’t know where hdr->flags be set to VIRTIO_NET_HDR_F_NEEDS_CSUM.

dpdk version is 21.11

Comment: can you please clarify your question as `RX TCP checksum is not working, or TX TCP checksum is not working, or both RX and TX checksum is not working`. Also please share the example that is run in guest to validate the same.. Note: as per your question title you are stating `dpdk Rx TCP checksum failed`

Comment: I request you to check both https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/kvm/patch/1307703377-3798-1-git-send-email-jasowang@redhat.com/ and https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html. As per the patch if the host has validated the checksum the guest can skip checksum in RX direction saving CPU cycles. Is your host validating the checksum and injecting to guest via virtio? Can you please clarify

Comment: can you please clarify your question as RX TCP checksum is not working, or TX TCP checksum is not working, or both RX and TX checksum is not working.     -->       "RX TCP checksum is not working"

Comment: looks like you accepted an answer, happy to see your issue is resolved `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum_verify`. were you able to nail down what caused `RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE`. as mentioned in my earlier comment is it host os which validates L4 hence bypassed in guest with https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/kvm/patch/1307703377-3798-1-git-send-email-jasowang@redhat.com/?

Comment: I have another confusion, what is the meaning of  "the checksum in packet may be wrong, but data integrity is valid".   is checksum a calculated value that is used to determine the integrity of data?   In fact, I can observe some mbuf->ol_flags is RX_L4_CKSUM_GOOD， another is RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE，why these mbufs ol_flags can be different?

Comment: these are good question, but as enquired `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum_verify` solved the issue? or is it because host validates l3|l4 for packets to guest os virtio hence `RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE`?

Comment: @stackinside yes, `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum_verify ` can solved this issue. Thank you for your patience, I have understood. guest driver does not calculate checksum, so it doesn't know if cheksum is good or bad.

Comment: @J.Heng so if you are claiming `the guest OS driver trust the Host OS checksum validation`. then why do you really need `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum_verify` to validate the packets? Since your question is `dpdk Rx TCP checksum failed` it means you were either sending good packets and checksum in guest failed. or you were sending bad checksum packet and the guest driver was returning good.

Comment: @J.Heng hence my answer will be `RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE` is returned if `guest os driver trusts the checksum calculated by host driver. If the guest does not trust the driver code in guest should execute if (hdr->flags & VIRTIO_NET_HDR_F_NEEDS_CSUM)`. This is actually done by header fields in virtio header (and not packet data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the original [commit](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/commit/5842289a546ceb0072bd7faccb93821e21848e07), `RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE` helps to cover the virtio / vhost use case and indicates that "the checksum in packet *may* be wrong, but data integrity is valid".

My takeaway from this explanation is that confirming the "data integrity" might be possible because of the very nature of this specific use case, but, since no checksum validation is done (the value is not recalculated), one cannot set `RX_L4_CKSUM_GOOD` or `RX_L4_CKSUM_BAD`. Hence `RX_L4_CKSUM_NONE`.

Perhaps it pays to add a printout of `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum_verify()` invocation (temporarily) to the application. If it reports that the checksum is valid, then above explanation should prove correct (no checksum failure).

Comment: My app is : `if ((p->ol_flags & (RTE_MBUF_F_RX_IP_CKSUM_BAD)) != 0) {return error}`; so according to the above; I should modify my app to `if ((p->ol_flags PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_MASK) == PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_BAD) {return error}`

Comment: The `NONE` flag is a combination of the corresponding `GOOD` and `BAD` ones. In this particular case, the driver sets `NONE`, that's why both `GOOD` and `BAD` bits are seen in `ol_flags`. The checksum status (as a whole) is a 2-bit **enum** value here. And the right way to check it is to apply the mask (`L4_CKSUM_MASK`) and compare (`==`) the resulting value with, say, `BAD` or `GOOD`, depending on what the app needs to check.